# MongoDB query array positional operator weird behavior

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema for mongoose:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    game: Number,
    words: Number,
    players: [{
        name: String,
        wordPercentage: Number,
        totalWords: Number
    }]
});
```

And what I would like to do is update the wordPercentage for every index in the array by doing `wordPercentage: (totalWords / totalGameWords) * 100`

I have tried:`db.gamedatas.findOneAndUpdate({game: 1}, {$set: { 'players.$.wordPercentage': (('players.$.totalWords' / totalGameWords) * 100 } });` and `totalGameWords` being a local variable.

But I am getting this error: `The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: players.$.wordPercentage`

I tired using `players.$[].wordPercentage` instead but I then get another error: `cannot use the part (players of players.$[].wordPercentage)`

Using `players.1.wordPercentage` works like a charm, but thats not what I am after sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
schema.findOne({game : 1})
            .exec()
            .then(doc => {
                doc.players.forEach((player,i,players)=>{
                   players[i].wordPercentage = (players[i].totalWords / players[i].totalGameWords) * 100
                })
                doc.save();
                return doc;
            })
            .catch(err=>{
               console.log(err)
            })
```

Comment: lovely, I always used callbacks than promises, I see how they are better, thanks!

Comment: Oh and I also did some small modifications to fit my needs, changed the schema.find to `schema.findOne` and changed the `totalWords` to my local variable rather than how you have it there, again, Thanks! :)

Comment: I changed `schema.find` too :D , again, Welcome :)